# python futures.as_completed stops responding after an error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have some code using futures that is working and providing output, until I hit and error and then the output stops.    The remainder of the processes continue to execute (I can see them running executing in the database), I'm just not able to capture the result.  What am I missing?

```
from concurrent import futures
import oracle_manager
import os

sql_statements=['select count(*) from PS_SCC_NTF_PREF',
'select count(*) from PS_SCC_STN_LTR_TBL',
'select count(*) from PS_SCC_TM_TRAN_AGR',
'select count(*) from PS_SCRTY_TBL_INST',
'select count(*) from PS_SCTN_CMBND',
'select count(*) from PS_SCTN_CMBND_TBL',
'select count(*) from PS_SEC_ITEM_CLS',
'select count(*) from PS_SESSION_TBL',
...]

def run_sql(sql):
  temp_connection = oracle_manager.OracleConnection(un, pw, tns)
  value = temp_connection.execute_count(sql)
  return (value, os.getpid())

worker_pool = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
wait_for = [worker_pool.submit(run_sql, sql_statement) for sql_statement in sql_statements] 

for f in futures.as_completed(wait_for):
  try:
    print(f.result())
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
((1069,), 23010)
((130464,), 23013)
((40220,), 23012)
((296372,), 23009)
((930954,), 23011)
((13836,), 23012)
((19707,), 23009)
((52130,), 23010)
((130707,), 23013)
((21,), 23011)
((276,), 23009)
((53157,), 23012)
((111,), 23009)
((381,), 23009)
An exception occurred running the following sql statement: "select count(*) from PS_SF_ACCTG_LN"
Oracle-Error-Code/Message: 600  ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kskqgetserviceid:nosvcidpdb1], [3], [0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

UGH.  After closer inspection of my oracle_manager, I found I had put an exit(1) in try/except block in my execute_count method when I was doing some debugging.  Removing the exit solved the problem.